# Handle the download of several tens of thousands files c#

Tags: c#, file, download, webclient, download-speed

I'm making a small software that download several tens of thousands files.
It's not efficient at all for now because i download each file once by once and so it's very slow, and also lot of files are less than 100ko.

Do you have any idea to improve the download speed ?

```
    /*******************************
        Worker work
    /********************************/
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        listCount = _downloadList.Count;
        // no GUI method !
        while (TotalDownloadFile < _downloadList.Count)
        {
            // handle closing form during download
            if (_worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                _mainView = null;
                _wc.CancelAsync();
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else if (!DownloadInProgress && TotalDownloadFile < listCount)
            {
                _lv = new launcherVersion(_downloadList[TotalDownloadFile]);
                var fileToDownloadPath = Info.getDownloadUrl() + _lv.Path;
                var saveFileToPath = Path.GetFullPath("./") + _lv.Path;
                if (Tools.IsFileExist(saveFileToPath))
                    File.Delete(saveFileToPath); // remove file if extist
                else
                    // create directory where the file will be created (use api this don't do anything on existing directory)
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(saveFileToPath));
                StartDownload(fileToDownloadPath, saveFileToPath);
                UpdateRemaingFile();
                _currentFile = TotalDownloadFile;
            }
        }
    }
```

Start Download Function

```
    /*******************************
        start the download of files
    /********************************/
    public void StartDownload(string fileToDownloadLink, string pathToSaveFile)
    {
        try
        {
            using (_wc = new WebClient())
            {
                _wc.DownloadProgressChanged += client_DownloadProgressChanged;
                _wc.DownloadFileCompleted += client_DownloadFileCompleted;
                _wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(fileToDownloadLink), pathToSaveFile);
                DownloadInProgress = true;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(fileToDownloadLink);
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            _worker.CancelAsync();
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could potentially use multi-threading and concurrency to download entire batches at once. You'd have to put some though into ensuring each thread completes successfully and ensure that files don't get downloaded twice.

Comment: `Do you have any idea to improve the download speed ?` Please show us the existing code.

Comment: You could at least tell us what protocol you are using. HTTP / FTP / SFTP / ...

Comment: [producer-consumer-dataflow-pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-implement-a-producer-consumer-dataflow-pattern)

Comment: I've edited my question , i sent my code, and i'm using HTTP

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-a-simple-parallel-foreach-loop may be of interest.

Comment: Please include the source code for `StartDownload`

Comment: @mjwills I added the StartDownload function

Comment: `else if (!DownloadInProgress && TotalDownloadFile < listCount)` The `!DownloadInProgress` check is what is ensuring you are only downloading one file at once...

Answer (score 0):

Expanding upon my comment. You could potentially use multi-threading and concurrency to download entire batches at once. You'd have to put some though into ensuring each thread completes successfully and ensure that files don't get downloaded twice. You would have to secure your centralized lists using something like [lock](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=VS.100).aspx).

I would personally implement 3 separate lists: `ReadyToDownload`, `DownloadInProgress`, and `DownloadComplete`.

`ReadyToDownload` would contain all objects that need to be downloaded. `DownloadInProgress` would contain both the item being downloaded and the Task handling the download. `DownloadComplete` would hold all objects that were downloaded and reference the Task that performed the download.

Each Task would hypothetically work better as an instance of a custom object. That object would take in a reference to each of the lists, and it would handle updating the lists once it work either completes or fails. In the event of a failure, you could either add a forth list to house the failed items, or reinsert them into the `ReadyToDownload` list.

Comment: "and reference the thread that performed the download" - why? I wouldn't even use Threads, but Tasks.